# Permutations of 0...N-1 with given properties

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

We have the sequence of natural numbers {0.....N-1}

where N=K^L (power), being K,L >1

I am looking for permutations of this sequence, {A(0)....A(N-1)}, such that for any given index m, 0<= m < N :

**floor( A(m+1)/K ) = A(m) mod (K^(L-1))**

For instance, for K=3, L=2, we have N=9. And 2 possible solutions are

{0,1,4,3,2,8,7,5,6}

{2,7,5,8,6,1,4,3,0}

My questions are

- Will there always exist a solution for any given K,L?
- If so, can an algorithm or general formula be found for any case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In effect, you are asking for a permutation of all L-digit numbers in base K (including those with leading zeros) such that the last $L-1$ digits of any number would be the first $L-1$ digits of the next one.

Well, that calls for [de Bruijn sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequences).

Comment: Have just taken a look at it and you're right, thanks. In fact the original problem was about a minimum length sequence, but didn't know of the link. So, I guess there is no general formula for the indexes but an algorithm?

Comment: Looks like so. Well, as to me, an algorithm is as good as formula.